# Facebook C# SDK - Mobile Web Page : Facebook Wall Post URL Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-wall

I am currently working on a mobile web page in asp.Net MVC2 that allows users to post to their walls. I have the following code that posts to the user's wall, but would like to instead have a redirect to Facebook's mobile "Post To my Wall" view to allow the user to add to the posted message and submit with a "Post" button or "Cancel". Do I have to recreate this view myself? It seems like something that a lot of sites would use.

```
 public string PostToWall(string code)
        {
            string authToken = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                authToken = GetAuthToken(code);
                FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient(authToken);
                dynamic user = app.Get("me");
                var id = user.id;
                var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                args["message"] = "Test Wall Post";
                args["caption"] = "Test Caption";
                args["description"] = "Test Description";
                args["name"] = "Test Name";
                //args["picture"] = "[your image URL]";
                //args["link"] = "[your link URL]";

                app.Post("/me/feed", args);
                return string.Empty;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.ErrorFormat("Error getting the Facebook authentication token. {0}", ex);
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Thanks!

[Edit] @OffBySome I set up a rough test using the facebook Javascript SDK and I set it to display: 'touch' but it still pops up in my safari iphone user agent.  I used this

```
attachment: {
                title: '<my title>',
                caption: '<my caption>',
                description: (
                        <my description>
                    ),
                name: '<name>',
                link:  '<link>',
                display: 'touch', },
```

But none of these attachments get added to my wall posts. Am I doing it wrong? Dialogs: Fb.Ui http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#xfbml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest for this would be to use the [Facebook javascript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) sdk and use the [FB.ui dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/) to allow the user to share.  You can set display=touch or display=wap for a mobile optimized dialog.

Comment: I set up a rough test and I'm wondering if it can redirect to the pop-up because I don't want it to "pop-up" on a mobile device. See my edits in my original post for more details.

Comment: Also, I cannot seem to get the action_links or attachment parameters to work (i.e. I cannot make hyperlinks or any predefined description to post to the wall.) Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please see my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551051/facebook-javascript-sdk-fb-ui-feed-wall-post-help

Comment: I ended up redirecting the users to the feed URL rather than use the FB.ui. Thanks for your response to my question though @OffBySome.